# How to get Java class' real module dependency?

Tags: java, java-11, java-platform-module-system, jlink, jdeps

My JDK version is OpenJDK 11.
My class File is **jmx.Main.class**

Here are my code.

```
package jmx;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

import javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException;
import javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException;
import javax.management.MBeanException;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.ReflectionException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstanceNotFoundException, AttributeNotFoundException, MalformedObjectNameException, ReflectionException, MBeanException  {
        /* Total number of processors or cores available to the JVM */
        MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        Object attribute = mBeanServer.getAttribute(new ObjectName("java.lang","type","OperatingSystem"), "TotalPhysicalMemorySize");
        Object attribute2 = mBeanServer.getAttribute(new ObjectName("java.lang","type","OperatingSystem"), "FreePhysicalMemorySize");
        System.out.println("Total memory: "+ Long.parseLong(attribute.toString()) / 1024  +"MB");
        System.out.println("Free  memory: "+ Long.parseLong(attribute2.toString()) / 1024  +"MB");
    }
}
```

It works fine when it runs in IDE. I want to use a custom jre. Then I use `jdeps` to analyze dependencies. The result is:

```
Main.class -> java.base
Main.class -> java.management
   jmx                                        -> java.io                                            java.base
   jmx                                        -> java.lang                                          java.base
   jmx                                        -> java.lang.invoke                                   java.base
   jmx                                        -> java.lang.management                               java.management
   jmx                                        -> javax.management                                   java.management
```

So I think `java.base` and `java.management` is the dependency modules.

Then I use `jlink` to generate my custom jre.

```
jlink --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\jmods" --add-modules java.base,java.management --output jre11
```

Before using my custom jre, I had run my code in cmd windows. It works fine.

Then I run the code in my jre. The code can't run and I got an error:

```
javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: No such attribute: TotalPhysicalMemorySize
```

So I think the reason is that some dependency modules is missing. I run `jlink` to generate a whole module jre. When I use the whole module jre, the code runs correctly again.

How can I get the real dependency modules? or It's a JDK's bug?

Comment: Pardon me if I am asking a silly question, but does your JAR file contain a `module-info.class` ? In other words is your JAR modular? I'm guessing you want to run it by simply double clicking on the file in Windows File Explorer, correct?

Comment: It's a single class, not a jar file. I run it in a cmd windows. My project does not contains a module-info. It does not necessary to have a module-info file in a project. It's an [automatic module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules).

Comment: You are using a reflective operation to query the attribute `"TotalPhysicalMemorySize"`. Static code analysis like `jdeps` can’t detect dynamic access. You have to add the module `jdk.management`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before JDK 9, the type `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` was an undocumented extension of `java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean`. So it was reasonable to use a reflective attribute query like `getAttribute(new ObjectName("java.lang","type","OperatingSystem"), "TotalPhysicalMemorySize")` which does not create a dependency to nonstandard APIs.

The advantage is also the disadvantage. When there is no dependency, a tool to analyse dependencies can’t detect a dependency.

When you add the module `jdk.management`, the extension will be available. Being part of a documented module also implies that when you are willing to accept a permanent dependency to the module, you can use the extended [`OperatingSystemMXBean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) directly.

```
import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class OSMX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OperatingSystemMXBean osBean
            = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);
        System.out.println("Total memory: "
            + osBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize() / (1024*1024)  +"MB");
        System.out.println("Free  memory: "
            + osBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize() / (1024*1024)  +"MB");
    }
}
```

Then, `jdeps` will report the dependency to `jdk.management` correctly.